# CSS background image animation top to bottom

Tags: css

I'm using CSS to animate a background image on hover.
Currently the CSS is making the background move from left to right.
I'd like to switch it to move from top to bottom.

Any suggestions on how to edit this CSS to achieve this?

.case-wrapper {width:600px;}

```
@-webkit-keyframes bgAnimationLeft {
    0%,
    100%,
    95% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
    48%,
    52% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0)
    }
}

@keyframes bgAnimationLeft {
    0%,
    100%,
    95% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
    48%,
    52% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0)
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bgAnimationLeft {
    0%,
    100%,
    95% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
    49%,
    51% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(15%, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(15%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(15%, 0, 0)
    }
}

@keyframes bgAnimationLeft {
    0%,
    100%,
    95% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
    49%,
    51% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(15%, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(15%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(15%, 0, 0)
    }
}


.bgAnimation-swaying-image-holder {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  border-left: 15px solid #fff;
  border-right: 15px solid #fff;
}

.bgAnimation-swaying-image-holder.bgAnimation-si-to-left .bgAnimation-swaying-image {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    -moz-animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.bgAnimation-swaying-image-holder .bgAnimation-swaying-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 120%;
    background-size: cover;
}

.bgAnimation-swaying-image-holder.bgAnimation-si-to-right .bgAnimation-swaying-image {
    right: 0;
    -webkit-animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    -moz-animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused
}

.bgAnimation-swaying-image-holder.bgAnimation-si-to-left .bgAnimation-swaying-image {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    -moz-animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused
}

.bgAnimation-swaying-image-holder:hover .bgAnimation-swaying-image {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    animation-play-state: running
}
```

See via codepen https://codepen.io/lisa-jaffe/pen/XWWWNaP

Comment: Also, a [mcve] should be within the question, not as an external link alone.

Comment: As a tip from developer to another, learn to read docs, and try to understand how things work by doing, it will save you hours and hours of development time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the x coordinate values and add them to y.
**translate3d(x, y, z)**

Here is modified CSS:

```
.case-wrapper {width:600px;}

@-webkit-keyframes bgAnimationLeft {
    0%,
    100%,
    95% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
    48%,
    52% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -35%, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -35%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -35%, 0)
    }
}

@keyframes bgAnimationLeft {
    0%,
    100%,
    95% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
    48%,
    52% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -35%, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -35%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -35%, 0)
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bgAnimationLeft {
    0%,
    100%,
    95% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
    49%,
    51% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 35%, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 35%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 35%, 0)
    }
}

@keyframes bgAnimationLeft {
    0%,
    100%,
    95% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
    49%,
    51% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 35%, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 35%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 35%, 0)
    }
}


.bgAnimation-swaying-image-holder {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  border-left: 15px solid #fff;
  border-right: 15px solid #fff;
}

.bgAnimation-swaying-image-holder.bgAnimation-si-to-left .bgAnimation-swaying-image {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    -moz-animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.bgAnimation-swaying-image-holder .bgAnimation-swaying-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 120%;
    background-size: cover;
}

.bgAnimation-swaying-image-holder.bgAnimation-si-to-right .bgAnimation-swaying-image {
    right: 0;
    -webkit-animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    -moz-animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused
}

.bgAnimation-swaying-image-holder.bgAnimation-si-to-left .bgAnimation-swaying-image {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    -moz-animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    animation: bgAnimationLeft 20s linear infinite forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused
}

.bgAnimation-swaying-image-holder:hover .bgAnimation-swaying-image {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    animation-play-state: running
}
```

You can change the value as per your requirement.